# How to cut the intersection of two objects use scripts

Tags: python, mesh

There are two mesh object, they have a certain intersection, how to cut it?
It's not merge, just cut one of them, they are still two objects.

Current status：
[image]

[image]

[image]

I want:

[image]

Comment: Switch to Edge select mode, Select one vertical edge and "Slide Edge" (G, G) with Snap to Edge enabled ... repeat for second side. Alternatively Boolean operator, but since top faces shares the same location it can generates issues.

Comment: this is move, not cutting

Comment: boolean difference with exact mode should do it

Comment: @ff114 yes :) that is why it wasn't post as regular answer, but also could be a solution and was relevant until you changed title with "scriptů ... comment includes also Boolean (modifier) tip and as Gorgious mentioned - it should work ...  what I tried now, he is right in this specific case :)

Comment: is the python tag a mistake or are you really asking how to do this in python?